# MongoDB Aggregation: Find about to expire products

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregation

I want to find products that will expired in 3 days and stock remaining is > 0 and I have the following aggregate pipeline:

```
   db.products.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "stocks",
      let: {
        stocks: "$stocks"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $in: [
                "$_id",
                "$$stocks"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            remaining: 1,
            expireDate: 1
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "stock"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      remaining: "$stock.remaining",
      expireDate: "$stock.expireDate"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      expireDate: {
        $lt: ISODate("2020-12-06")
      },
      remaining: {
        $gt: 0
      }
    }
  }
])
```

from the following data below (the `expireDate` is in Stock collection):

```
db={
  products: [
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("63515ad7d5f84ecbaac38f1e"),
      "code": "1",
      "name": "Coca-Cola",
      "pricePerItem": NumberInt(2),
      "stocks": [
        ObjectId("63515ad7d5f84ecbaac38f20"),
        ObjectId("63515b04d5f84ecbaac38f2e")
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("63515aeed5f84ecbaac38f24"),
      "code": "2",
      "name": "Fanta",
      "pricePerItem": NumberInt(4),
      "stocks": [
        ObjectId("63515aeed5f84ecbaac38f26")
      ]
    }
  ],
  stocks: [
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("63515ad7d5f84ecbaac38f20"),
      "count": NumberInt(10),
      "remaining": NumberInt(0),
      "costPerItem": NumberInt(1),
      "expireDate": ISODate("2020-12-05")
    },
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("63515aeed5f84ecbaac38f26"),
      "count": NumberInt(102),
      "remaining": NumberInt(10),
      "costPerItem": NumberInt(3),
      "expireDate": ISODate("2020-12-10")
    },
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("63515b04d5f84ecbaac38f2e"),
      "count": 1,
      "remaining": 1,
      "costPerItem": NumberInt(20),
      "expireDate": ISODate("2020-12-20")
    }
  ]
}
```

I have also created a Mongo playgound via this link: https://mongoplayground.net/p/t1-ZMGzajf7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your criteria for `remaining` and `expireDate` into a subpipeline in `$lookup`. `$unwind` at the end to keep only matched record.

```js
db.products.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "stocks",
      "localField": "stocks",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $ne: [
                    {
                      $ifNull: [
                        "$expireDate",
                        null
                      ]
                    },
                    null
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $gt: [
                    "$remaining",
                    0
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $lt: [
                    {
                      "$dateSubtract": {
                        "startDate": "$expireDate",
                        "unit": "day",
                        "amount": 3
                      }
                    },
                    "$$NOW"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "stocksLookup"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$stocksLookup"
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/h_dl33aZziG)

Comment: Thank you. That is what I want. But the date comparing part is not working.
I created another playgound. When it run it should not show Fanta.
https://mongoplayground.net/p/_XmnkeFdysq

Comment: @vanna because I am using `$$NOW`, which is referring to the current date. I am comparing `expireDate + 3 day` to `$$NOW`. So your fanta record is still matched. If you replace `$$NOW` with a certain thresholding date, says 2020-02-28, the record will not be returned

Comment: Sorry it still not working. Let say Fanta expire is "2020-02-20" and now is "2020-02-18", it should show Fanta because it's expiring in 2 days

Comment: it works when I change from $dateAdd to $dateSubtract.

Comment: Btw, How to exclude Stocks without expireDate value?

Comment: @vanna updated the answer to have extra checking for null/non-existent `expireDate`. Also incorporated your fix for `$dateSubtract`

Comment: sorry for asking too many. How to sort by expireDate? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @vanna just add one more `$sort` stage at the end of pipeline like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uGeT5RmQKt_)